# SBG SMIL animation flicking but not animating smoothly

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, smil

Can someone tell me why my animation isn't working please? I have two shapes I am trying to tween. I have equal number of coordinates. Both shapes can be seen in the codepen link below.

http://codepen.io/tands/pen/myKPPb

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500px"  height="500px" viewBox="0 0 453.5 290">

  <path 

  id="p1" 
  fill="#000000" 
  d="
                      M226.8, 34.9 
                      C146.3, 34.9, 71.5, 22, 8.9, 0 
                      C3.1, 20.1, 0, 41.3, 0, 63.2 
                      C0, 188.5, 101.5, 290, 226.8, 290 
                      S453.5, 188.5, 453.5, 63.2 
                      c0-21.9-3.1-43.1-8.9-63.2 
                      C382.1, 22, 307.2, 34.9, 226.8, 34.9z 
                      H0z
                      "

/>


<animate xlink:href="#p1"
attributeName="d"
attributeType="XML"
from="
                      M226.8, 34.9 
                      C146.3, 34.9, 71.5, 22, 8.9, 0 
                      C3.1, 20.1, 0, 41.3, 0, 63.2 
                      C0, 188.5, 101.5, 290, 226.8, 290 
                      S453.5, 188.5, 453.5, 63.2 
                      c0-21.9-3.1-43.1-8.9-63.2 
                      C382.1, 22, 307.2, 34.9, 226.8, 34.9z 
                      H0z
                      "
to="


                      M8.9,
                      0

                                C3.1,
                                20.1,
                                0,
                                41.3,
                                0,
                                63.2

                      C3.1,
                      20.1,
                      0,
                      41.3,
                      0,
                      63.2

                      C0,
                      188.5,
                      101.5,
                      290,
                      226.8,
                      290

                      S453.5,
                      188.5,
                      453.5,
                      63.2

                      c0-21.9-3.1-43.1-8.9-63.2

                              C0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0

                      H8.9z



                      "
dur="2s"

repeatCount="indefinite"


/>
```

Answer (score 1):

They don't have the same number of commands. Some of the paths have extra `z` commands (or some of them are missing `z` commands depending on your point of view).

Changing the degenerate case to this...

```
                              C0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0z
```

Makes everything animate smoothly.

Comment: Thanks, the animation works now but not as I was hoping http://codepen.io/tands/pen/myKPPb looks weird :(

Comment: Your degenerate C is weird so your animation is weird too.

Comment: Thanks, i think i've corrected that however it doesn't animate as I was hoping. It fills up from right to left, i was hoping it would lift up from the middle like a mask. The reason I dont want to use an actual mask is because its going on a background image.

Comment: I suggest investigating using an elliptical arc or perhaps more than one C command.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this is killing my brain cells :( in the words of Arny "I'll be back"